# Array/loop behaviour

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have a dataset of three shops (Winkel1-3) and I would like to extract the addresses. What I've built extracts the names and then the addresses in stead of the combination of both. I'm sure I've built a flawed loop but I can't figure out what to change.

**My dataset:**

```
<ul id="itemsList">
    <li class="citem ">
        <a alt="Winkel 1" href="/Zuid-Holland/Delft/Winkel1">Winkel1</a>
        Buitenwatersloot 51,2613TB
    </li>
    <li class="citem ">
        <a alt="Winkel 2" href="/Zuid-Holland/Delft/Winkel2">Winkel 2</a>
        Laan van Van der Gaag 75,2627BX
    </li>
    <li class="citem ">
        <a alt="Winkel 3" href="/Zuid-Holland/Delft/Winkel3">Winkel 3</a>
        Achterom 89,2611PM
    </li>
</ul>
```

**My scraper:**

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.mydomaintestdata.nl/Zuid-Holland/Delft"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@id="itemsList"]/li')
        loop = sel.xpath('/html')
        for site in loop:
            adres = sites.xpath('.//a/text()').extract(), 
                    sites.xpath('text()').extract()
        print adres
```

**This returns two arrays:**

```
[Winkel1, Winkel2, Winkel3],['Buitenwatersloot 51,2613TB','Laan van Van der Gaag 75,2627BX','Achterom 89,2611PM']
```

**What I would like:**

```
[Winkel1,'Buitenwatersloot 51,2613TB'],[Winkel2, 'Laan van Van der Gaag 75,2627BX'],[Winkel3, 'Achterom 89,2611PM']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `li` elements and get the link and test for each li in the loop:

```
sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@id="itemsList"]/li')
for site in sites:
    print site.xpath('./a/text()').extract(), site.xpath('text()').extract()
```